# Filter Select according to NULL values

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

removing row on the basis of function output in postgresql :

in following query i am finding the sum of settlement value having value less then zero

```
   select order_id , order_item_id , 
          case when sum(settlement_value) < 0  then
                     sum(settlement_value) 
            end
  from 
       "Recon".fk_courier_return 
 group by 
        order_item_id, order_id
```

output is :

```
 Order id               Order_item_id  case

"OD101176788313080800";"115303430";
"OD40814018539";       "91216839";   -76.31
"OD40627030417";        "80207748";
"OD40913016810";       "98742811";
 "OD40701060277";       "80945680";
"OD100995986740582701";"108843075";  -42.07
"OD102293318278386300";"160498343";
 "OD40825127281";      "94066239";   -78.59
"OD200943992437302100";"106376239";
"OD40811280064";       "90512463";
"OD102056004796760300";"150562685";
 "OD40705090946";      "81791269";
"OD100996265730486401";"108855460";
"OD301050807164753201";"111119783";
"OD000825719620275400";" 100799584";
"OD001027651714425302"; "110064133";
"OD102181807536975500"; "156169384";
"OD000790021256135600";"99916743";
"OD101801498273347001";"139754487";
"OD40825034475";       "93908112";     -78.59
```

now i want to remove all row that are not having value in case column

what changes should i do in my query

Comment: Do you want to `delete` those rows (permanently) from the table, or just exclude them from the result of the `select` statement

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  exclude    exclude them from the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question (not showing rows on the basis of function output) you could rewrite your query this way:

```
SELECT
  order_id,
  order_item_id,
  sum_settlement_value
FROM (
  SELECT order_id, order_item_id, 
         CASE WHEN sum(settlement_value) < 0  then
                   sum(settlement_value) 
         END AS sum_settlement_value
  FROM 
    "Recon".fk_courier_return 
   GROUP BY 
     order_item_id, order_id
) s
WHERE
  sum_settlement_value IS NOT NULL
```

(this could be useful if your function is too complicated) but if you just don't want to show rows not having a negative value, it is better to use HAVING clause:

```
SELECT
  order_id,
  order_item_id,
  SUM(settlement_value)
FROM 
   "Recon".fk_courier_return 
GROUP BY 
  order_item_id,
  order_id
HAVING
  SUM(settlement_value) < 0
```

Answer (score 0):

An another approach by avoiding `CASE WHEN`and using `CTE`

```
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT order_id
        ,order_item_id
        ,sum(settlement_value) settlement_value
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY order_item_id
        ,order_id
    )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE settlement_value < 0
```